# How to make an integer input into blocks of 2 digits starting from the right side

Tags: python

example, lets say the input is 12463
then the code will turn the input will turn into a list [1,24,63]

I tried this on my own but it starts from the left, so it would look like [12,46,3]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Test your input on 1-3 digit numbers, and you end up with something like this... `if x >= 100: num = x % 100; lst.append(num); x = x // 100; else: lst.append(num)`. You just need to wrap in a loop for larger inputs

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a string, and then iterate by index from the end in steps of -2:

```
>>> n = 12463
>>> [int(str(n)[max(i-2,0):i]) for i in range(len(str(n)), 0, -2)][::-1]
[1, 24, 63]
```

Comment: But the author wants it [12,46,3] not [1, 24, 63] ..

Comment: @Nova  "How to make an integer input into blocks of 2 digits **starting from the right side**"

Comment: OP said explicitly that `[12, 46, 3]` is what their best attempt produces, but `[1, 24, 63]` is what they *want*.

Answer (score 0):

```
def slice_it(num):
    a = str(num)
    sliced = []

    if not len(a) % 2:
        for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
            sliced.append(''.join(a[i:i + 2]))
    else:
        sliced.append(a[0])
        for i in range(1, len(a), 2):
            sliced.append(''.join(a[i:i + 2]))

    returrn list(map(int, sliced))
```

```
>>> slice_it(12345)
[1, 23, 45]
>>> slice_it(123456)
[12, 34, 56]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea, using modulo like omermikhailk but taking advantage of `iter`: when you `zip` an iterator with itself, it gives you pairs. We pad the stringified integer with a space (`0` would work, too) if it's of uneven length, then we can just grab 2 characters at a time with the `iter`/`zip` strategy and cast them back to integers.

```py
n = "12345"
n = " "*(len(n) % 2) + n # add padding

n_iter = iter(n)

# [1, 23, 45]
result = [int(''.join(pair)) for pair in zip(n_iter, n_iter)]
```